# Initializing new file in a switch statement

Tags: java, file-io, initialization, switch-statement

I'm having trouble with a file initiation. Basically, I want my problem to randomly choose a file. This is the code I have currently:

```
public void doFile () throws FileNotFoundException
   {

      File one = new File ("RJOpening.txt");
      File two = new File ("RJBalcony.txt");
      File choice;

      int n = (int)(Math.random() * 2);

      switch (n)
      {
         case 1: choice = one; break;
         case 2: choice = two; break;
         default: break;
      } 
      Scanner input = new Scanner (choice);
```

The above gives me a compiler error on the Scanner input line, saying that variable "choice" was not initialized. I tried doing File choice = new File (), but obviously that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, consider n = 100.

Answer (score 1):

Do in simple way

```
 final File choice; // make it final
 int n = (int)(Math.random() * 2); // only 0 or 1 as two possible values

 if(n == 0){ 
     choice = one;
 }else{
     choice = two;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells you that if `n` is neither `1` nor `2`, `choice` would remain uninitialized. You need to make sure that `random` is constrained to the range of two values (zero and one is typical, but you could use 1 and 2 if you wish), and also add a default that assigns the value of `null`. It is safe, because the code above guarantees that `null` is never assigned:

```
int n = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
switch (n % 2) // Now n is either zero or 1
{
   case 0: choice = one; break;
   case 1: choice = two; break;
   default: choice = null; break;
}
```

However, for only two values this is overkill: an `if`/`else` would be quite sufficient, and it wouldn't require you to provide a useless `default`.

For more than two values you would be better putting your files into an array, and picking an index at random, like this:

```
File allFiles[] = new File[] {
    new File ("RJOpening.txt"),
    new File ("RJBalcony.txt"),
    new File ("RJClosing.txt"),
    new File ("RJWindow.txt"),
    ...
};
int n = (int)(Math.random() * allFiles.length);
File choice = allFiles[n % allFiles.length];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
  switch (n)
  {
     case 0: choice = one; break;
     case 1: choice = two; break;
     default: choice = null; break;
  }
```

`Math.random()` returns a value in [0, 1], when
you multiply by 2, this interval becomes [0, 2),
when you cast to `int` this gives either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to come up with a random number, using that random number to set the value of a variable, and using that variable to open a file, why not put the last line

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(choice);
```

into the switch statement, as separate things?

```
switch (n)
      {
         case 1:  Scanner input = new Scanner ("RJOpening.txt"); break;
         case 2:  Scanner input = new Scanner ("RJBalcony.txt"); break;
         default: break;
      }
```

Comment: Also, case1: should be case 0: